# GET Request after POST(login)

Tags: c#, http

I have a web site which i check my product list daily. I want to make a desktop program for it.

I need to login to the web site first then i go to site.com/v1/ProductList which is an xml document. I have managed to login with this code:

```
            CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FirstURL);
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        //Get the response from the server and save the cookies from the first request..
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        cookies = response.Cookies;
        string postData = "Username=x&Password=x&List=1&Submit=Submit";
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); //recover cookies First request
        getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
        getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
        newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
        newStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Here i am successfully logged in.
But after this, if i create a new get request for my list(site.com/v1/ProductList) and get request it redirects me to the login page.

Edit: I just realized that i cant get any cookies after i login. It says "'enumeration yielded no results'".

I have no idea how to fix it right now.

Thanks

Comment: are you storing the cookies?

Comment: `getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();` you need to save this cookiecontainer in a variable and use that on subsequent requests. I'm sure this is a duplicate, can't be bothered to use the search.

Comment: Yes. However, now i just realized even though i successfully login(I checked html source), my response cookies are empty !!! It says 'enumeration yielded no results'

Comment: @CodeCaster i have found several posts about this issue however, none of them were answered.

Comment: Try setting `AllowAutoRedirect` to false, then look at your cookie container.

Comment: Still nothing count is 0 and this "'enumeration yielded no results'"

Comment: @icemanind I just realized that i only deleted AllowAutoRedirect instead of changing its value to false. Now it works like a charm. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, By default, its set to `true`, so it requires an explicit set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```

to this:

```
getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

Make sure you actually set it to `false` and don't just delete the line because, by default, it gets set to `true`.